# Long exact sequence for exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to D \to 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

It is known from homological algebra context that if we have a short exact sequence $$0\to A \to B \to C \to 0$$ of $R$-modules, then it induces a long exact sequence,

$$0 \to Hom_R(C,X) \to Hom_R(B, X) \to Hom_R(A, X) \to Ext^1_R(C,X) \to \cdots$$ for any $R$-module $X.$

My question is the following: Let $0 \to A \to B \to C \to D \to 0$ be a exact sequence of $R$-modules. Does there any analogous long exact sequence exist?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we produce a long exact sequence in cohomology from more than just short exact sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479953/can-we-produce-a-long-exact-sequence-in-cohomology-from-more-than-just-short-exa)

Comment: A "long" exact sequence (not necessarily infinite) gives a spectral sequence. If you know how to build spectral sequences from filtration, perhaps you can work it out yourself.